# How do I propagate the value of a property to the property of other types that are part of my class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have these classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractClazz {

    @Id
    protected int id;
    protected Instant createdAt;
    protected String createdBy;

    //getters and setters

    @PrePersist
    private void prePersist() {
        setCreatedAt(Instant.now());
    }

}

public class ConcreteClazzA extends AbstractClazz {

    private String name;

    //getters and setter
}

public class ConcreteClazzB extends AbstractClazz {

    private ConcreteClazzA clazzA;

    private String name;

    //getters and setter
}
```

How can I set the createdBy (getting the current user) at ConcreteClazzB when I persist ConcreteClazzA? I can't use @PrePersist because I have  to mantain the independency of components.

How can I set the same createdAt in both class?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MappedSuperclass` annotation

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractClazz {
```